# How can I make Google Chrome use my custom Bing Search settings?

Tags: google-chrome

In Google Chrome, one can select a piece of text on a web page, right click and select "Search with Bing" (Or whatever search engine one has set as the default)
However, I'm having trouble getting Chrome to use my preferred locale for Bing.

I have my English Windows 7 location set to Switzerland, but I have set my Bing preferences to use the U.S. version of Bing. So when I simply browse to http://bing.com I end  up on the U.S. Bing, just the way I want.

But when I select a piece of text, right click and do Search with Bing, it uses the Swiss Bing.
I have even set my custom search engine in Chrome to be the US Bing by setting it to:
http://www.bing.com/?scope=web&setmkt=en-us
but I still end up in
http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=fr-CH
(which even doesn't make sense, since I'm in the de-CH part of Switzerland.

Anyone have any ideas? How can I force Chrome to use the U.S. Bing?

Comment: As an experiment change the location to US, see if it works now.

Comment: Have changed the location to US, still bringing up French-Swiss Bing.

Comment: Which OS? maybe your DNS cache needs clearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm..
I removed the Bing entry I had and added a new one:
`http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-US&q=%s`

And now it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

From within Chrome select `Options - Search - Manage Search Options` to select the engine you wish to use.

Comment: That is exactly what I have done already without success. I will clarify my question.